# tail logback log files with log level coloring in linux server

Tags: linux, logging, logback

We are migrating from log4j to logback, and with log4j we are using multitail with colorscheme to tail our log files with log level coloring. 
Can multitail do the same for logback ? 
is there any other simple solution for logback file tailing with color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what file formats are supported by multitail per default but you can easily create a new color scheme for logback (see multitail.conf). I added the current log4j colorscheme as an example:

```
colorscheme:log4j
cs_re:magenta::
cs_re:magenta:/
cs_re:blue:^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*,[0-9]*
cs_re_s:blue,,bold:^[^ ]* *[^,]*,[^ ]* *[0-9]* *(DEBUG) *[^ ]* [^ ]* *(.*)$
cs_re_s:green:^[^ ]* *[^,]*,[0-9]* *[0-9]* *(INFO) *[^ ]* [^ ]* *(.*)$
cs_re_s:yellow:^[^ ]* *[^,]*,[0-9]* *[0-9]* *(WARN) *[^ ]* [^ ]* *(.*)$
cs_re_s:red:^[^ ]* *[^,]*,[0-9]* *[0-9]* *(ERROR) *[^ ]* [^ ]* *(.*)$
cs_re_s:red,,bold:^[^ ]* *[^,]*,[0-9]* *[0-9]* *(FATAL) *[^ ]* [^ ]* *(.*)$
cs_re_s:white,,bold:^[^ ]* *[^,]*,[0-9]* *[0-9]* *[A-Z]* *(.*)
```