# Is possible to change the forecolor of log4j?

Tags: log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a log4j console appender use different colors for different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848325/making-a-log4j-console-appender-use-different-colors-for-different-threads)

I am using Apache log4j with XML based configuration.i want to know is it is possible to change the color of font with different level of log4j.

Thanks

Comment: Log4J just generates text, it has no control over how you choose to view it.

Comment: You might need another skin? For a backcolor, you'd get a backskin, but for a forecolor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this resource : http://marc.info/?l=log4j-user&m=120574713010072

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it, but people seem to suggest [`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) with Log4J color scheme:

```
$ multitail -cS log4j -f logfile.log
```

See also:

- [Making a log4j console appender use different colors for different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848325)
- [tail logback log files with log level coloring in linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144693)